# Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2019 to display tab groups title on the bottom instead of top (as in VS2017)?

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017 I have some windows like Output, Package Manager Console, Call Stack etc. with title at the bottom:

[image: VS2017 tabs titles]

The same in VS2019 looks like this:

[image: VS2019 tabs titles]

**Question:** Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2019 to display tab groups title on the bottom instead of top (as in VS2017)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on Output and Package Manager Console tabs and select **Dock**. It should return them to the default position at the bottom.